# apache 2.2 subdomain proxypass configuration with jetty 8

Tags: apache2, jetty, subdomain, mod-proxy, jetty-8

i am trying to proxypass a subdomain xxx.yyy.de to a jetty webapp on yyy.de:8080/app.
First i followed the documentation http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_mod_proxy which is pretty straight forward i guess. 
So my virtual host config looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName xxx.yyy.de

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / http://yyy:8080/app/
</VirtualHost>
```

Doing this results in a 302 forward from apache to: xxx.yyy.de/app/ instead of yyy.de:8080/app/

I tried several different combinations, none of them got me working so i wonder what i am doing wrong here and how to do it right?

I guess some rewriting could solve this, but that seems like the wrong way to me as according to the apache/jetty docs it should be much simpler.

Best Regards,
Sven

**Edit**
Well, it seems the problem is i am running a grails app behind this on my jetty.
However i solved it by using tomcat with its virtual host feature. Then my config works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me in my Ubuntu 12.10 laptop here is what I did:

1. Create /etc/apache2/available-sites/jetty
2. sudo a2enmod proxy_http
3. sudo a2ensite jetty
4. sudo service apache2 restart

Apache virtual host config file:

```
      <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName jetty.valkiria
        ProxyRequests Off
        <Proxy *:80>
          Order deny,allow
          Allow from all
        </Proxy>
        ProxyPass / http://valkiria:8080/
        ProxyPreserveHost On
     <VirtualHost *:80>
```

Comment: I guess i cannot mark your answer as solution as it does not work for my specific problem. However it would work too with tomcat and its virtual host.